# Community standard page content layout placement issue/understanding

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I am using Napili template with communities.I have created community page (Standard option) and choose to go with "2 columns, 1:2 ration". What I observed with standard layouts usually that left-hand columns get placed at the top and right-hand section at the bottom when viewing in the mobile.

Suppose there is the page with "2 columns with a 1:1 ratio". This looks on the desktop like this (as expected). I have placed 1 lightning component in each.

[image]

And when I view the same page in mobile, it looks like this as expected (left column on top and right column below that).

[image]

Now when I try the same components placement with "2 columns, 1:2 ratio", I am finding some different behavior. When I view in desktop thing looks good as expected:

[image]

But when I view the same page in mobile I am getting unexpected result. Left column is placed under right column.

[image]

Not sure if someone else have noticed or faced this issue. Or this is expected behavior.

Am I missing something here in understanding the layout responsiveness? 
Is there any thumb rule how column placement is decided in smaller screen?

Also last point, if I plan to go with custom content layout with similar column design then same issue will be coming out again?

Hope Salesforce gurus over here can help.

Thanks

Comment: what is Napili template? is this some feature related to communities in Lightning?

Comment: It is a standard template available for communities in salesforce.